# withdraw eth from contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, transactions, address.transfer

I have contract and function which accepts ether. How can I transfer ether from contract to any other wallet?

I'm using ganache-cli. Function work, and I spent 10 eth on contract(private network). Now I want to get them back

```
  contract Account {
    mapping (address => uint) balance;

            function accept(uint postId) payable public {
                balance[msg.sender] += msg.value;
                uint beforeWeight = posts[postId].weight;
            }
```

this function takes my ether from wallet, I want to take eth from contract to my wallet

```
 function transfer(uint amount) payable public {
            address(this).transfer(amount);
        }

    }
```

Comment: So what's wrong with the `transfer()` function? where is the error what is not working? how did you check?

Comment: when i call this metod  msg sender loose eth instead of receiving eth from contract.